# CSV Reader not enough values to unpack (expected 11, got 1)

Tags: python, csv

I got a problem using the csv reader.
I want to read a csv file line by line and print out the second entry of each line.
All entrys of a line are written in one cell end separated by ','

It looks like this: 
0.00,457.00,0.00,862.00,12892,32575,"LAX",11292,30325,"DEN",11,

I tried this code:

```
    with open(file_path, 'r', newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        for line in reader:
            passangers, freight, mail, distance, origin_airport_id, origin_city_marked_id, origin, dest_airport_id, dest_city_marked_id, dest, month = line
            print(freight)
```

but I get: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 11, got 1)

This code worked for me some time ago in another project so I really don't know why it doesn't work now. I tried different delimiters ( ' ; ' , space ,  etc.) but it was basically a guess because I don't know what else to do

Comment: If you `print(line)` what returns?

Comment: Why not try pandas? `import pandas as pd, df = pd.read_csv(file_path), df['freight']`. the last line assumes your csv has a header row

Comment: if i print(line) before the passangers,... line i get: [0.00,457.00,0.00,862.00,12892,32575,"LAX",11292,30325,"DEN",11,]

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you use `csv.DictReader` to structure your logic. Naming such a large number of variables is likely, as here, to lead to confusion.

Here's an example where we provide the `fieldnames` argument with a list. Note that there *are* 12 fields, since your line ends with a comma. Since `field_list` only has 11 elements, the final column is assigned the key `None`. This is apparent when you print the dictionary.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO('0.00,457.00,0.00,862.00,12892,32575,"LAX",11292,30325,"DEN",11,')

field_list = ['passengers', 'freight', 'mail', 'distance', 'origin_airport_id',
              'origin_city_marked_id', 'origin', 'dest_airport_id',
              'dest_city_marked_id', 'dest', 'month']

# replace mystr with open(file_path, 'r', newline='')
with mystr as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=field_list)
    for line in reader:
        print(line)

OrderedDict([('passengers', '0.00'),
             ('freight', '457.00'),
             ('mail', '0.00'),
             ('distance', '862.00'),
             ('origin_airport_id', '12892'),
             ('origin_city_marked_id', '32575'),
             ('origin', 'LAX'),
             ('dest_airport_id', '11292'),
             ('dest_city_marked_id', '30325'),
             ('dest', 'DEN'),
             ('month', '11'),
             (None, [''])])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that you try to squeeze list with 12 elements into 11 elements.

Try:

```
    passangers, freight, mail, distance, origin_airport_id, origin_city_marked_id, origin, dest_airport_id, dest_city_marked_id, dest, month, element = line
```

Simplified example of the original problem:

```
$ cat list.py 
line = ['a','b','c']
a,b = line

$ python list.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 2, in <module>
    a,b = line
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```